# Find Column and format as Date

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a several columns in my excel worksheets which are all named as "Date". I want to write a code which will find all date columns in all worksheets and format the values in that column as "dd/mm/yyyy;@" .

In the code below I tried writing Columns("Date").Select instead of Columns("E:E").Select but this is not working. Can anyone suggest me how to fix this?

Thanks for your time and suggestions.

```
Sub dateformat()      
Dim ws As Worksheet     
For Each ws In Worksheets         
Columns("E:E").Select         
Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"             
Next ws  
End Sub
```

Comment: Are all "E" columns in all worksheets Dates? or "Dates" can be in any column? If in all sheets Col E is the date then you are missing "ws." before the `Columns("E:E")` :)

Comment: @ Sid: Thanks for your response. The dates can be in any columns. Also, I have several date columns in one worksheets.

Comment: One last question. Are the headings "Dates" in Row 1 in all worksheets?

Comment: @ Sid: Yes, For eg: The column named "date" is in range (E:E), (F:F) etc on one sheet and (Az:Az), (B:B) on other sheet.

Comment: were you able to test the below code?

Comment: @ Sid, Yes I tested the code and it worked fine for my dummy file (when I entered the date to test) but for my actual file, its not working because I think it has some formatting issue. I am attaching my file here and would appreciate if you can help me fix that.

Comment: you will have to upload the file at www.wikisend.com or skydrive and share the link here :)

Comment: @ Sid: Thanks :) Here is the link: http://wikisend.com/download/974176/Test_File.xlsx. Also, in the original file these date values are formatted as "dd/mm/yyyy;@" but on runinng the lookup function in VBA excel, these values get weird.

Comment: I have updated the post below :) Check the section after Followup. Now test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nupur, Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

        Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(what:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        ExitLoop = False

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            ws.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
            Do While ExitLoop = False
                Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                    ws.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
                Else
                    ExitLoop = True
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

The reason you are getting those errors is because your column is formatted as text. Try this. This works :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).Find(what:="Date", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        ExitLoop = False

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            ws.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

            lastRow = ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
            ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 2 To lastRow
                With ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i)
                    .FormulaR1C1 = .Value
                End With
            Next i

            ws.Columns(aCell.Column).AutoFit

            Do While ExitLoop = False
                Set aCell = ws.Rows(1).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                    ws.Columns(aCell.Column).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

                    lastRow = ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
                    ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                    For i = 2 To lastRow
                        ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & i).Value
                    Next i
                Else
                    ExitLoop = True
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Answer (score 0):

Can you incorporate some of this code(modify to fit your req's)?

```
varLookFor1 = Format(Date - 1, "[$-409]mmmm-yy;@")
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=varLookFor1, LookIn:=xlValues).Activate
```

Comment: @ Andrew: I tried your code and its giving me compile error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".